# Unable to provide effective batch size in tensorflow keras model causing OOM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train a tensorflow keras model with input shapes as shown below.

```
x_train = (729124, 50, 5) 
y_train = (729124,)
```

My model is defined as follows

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(50,5), activation='relu'))
# model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, dropout=0.1, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer="adam")
```

On training the model using following code

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

I always get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/VOTAZBZ/Documents/Thesis/Code/ma_sajid/ml_models/RNN_train.py", line 124, in <module>
    shuffle=True, callbacks=[callback, tensorboard_callback]) #callbacks=[callback, callback1, tensorboard_callback])
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 797, in fit
    shuffle=False))
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1338, in train_validation_split
    functools.partial(_split, indices=train_indices), arrays)
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 617, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 617, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1335, in _split
    return array_ops.gather_v2(t, indices)
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 4541, in gather_v2
    batch_dims=batch_dims)
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 4524, in gather
    return gen_array_ops.gather_v2(params, indices, axis, name=name)
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 3755, in gather_v2
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "C:\Tools\Python\3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6653, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[583299,50,5] and type double on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:GatherV2]
```

I have understood that there is some memory overflow and hence wanted to reduce my batch sizes. But what I found surprising here is that the batch size I give is ineffective as I always get the above error where the tensor is trying to allocate a tensor for size `[583299,50,5]` but i guess I should be expecting something like `[batch_size,50,5]`. May I know what is wrong in the above implementation. How can I effectively give the batch size for training and hence avoid memory overflow.

Any help in solving this issue will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is a normal behaviour.

You are directly giving to the model the whole array and asking it to batch every 256 sample. By doing so even if you ask for only a 256 batch computation, at some point it will allocate the whole array.

What you need to do in order to allocate only a subset is to use a `Generator`, that will only yield a batch of data.

Here is the link to what you are looking for : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence

Once you've a running Sequence object which when called give you a `(X, 50 ,5) and (1,)` pair, you can call the fit as usual and remove the `batch_size` argument.

```py
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . It worked. I created the data with `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` as a sequence object and then fed it to `model.fit` and it worked fine without any problems.